# HTML::ENTITIES for URL encoding

Tags: perl, cgi, url-encoding

i am not sure what is wrong with this code, i am trying to remove special characters from the URL
for example:- `http://google.com/>"<script>alert(2121)</script>`

this triggers the javscript, i want to encode the '<>&"' from URL
so this is my code which i am trying to execute.

```
my $cgi = CGI->new();
use HTML::Entities;
sub escapeParams {
       my( $self ) = shift;

        my @params  = $self->query->param('<>&"');

        foreach my $param ( @params ) {
            #    $self->query->param( $param, HTML::Entities::encode( $self->query->param( $param ) ) );
            $self->query->param( HTML::Entities::encode($param), HTML::Entities::encode( $self->query->param( $param ) ) );
            print $self->query->param( $param );
        }

}
escapeParams($cgi);
```

Answer (score 3):

How do you output your HTML now? Say you have

```
print(qq{<a href="$link_url">$link_text</a>\n});
```

Replace it with

```
use CGI qw( escapeHTML );

my $link_url_html  = escapeHTML($link_url);
my $link_text_html = escapeHTML($link_text);

print(qq{<a href="$link_url_html">$link_text_html</a>\n});
```

Personally, I use Template-Toolkit.

```
<a href="[% link.url %]">[% link.text %]</a>                # WRONG!
<a href="[% link.url | html %]">[% link.text | html %]</a>  # ok
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but problem is if the user directly puts wrong URL in the browser http://google.com/>"<script>alert(2121)</script> then it triggers the javascript for that i am using above code please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: If they place that in the URL in the browser address box, they get a 404 page from Google. The JavaScript is not executed. The JavaScript is only executed if *your script* improperly builds HTML, and I showed you how to properly build HTML.

Comment: i am not talking about google :) this for some other site which is in cgi perl http://example.com/>"<script>alert(2121)</script>, if you hit this url to browser it executes the popup first and i need to eliminate those script tags from the URL

Comment: No, it doesn't. The JavaScript is only executed if *your script* improperly builds HTML, and I showed you how to properly build HTML.

Comment: i am facing this issue in IE browser only http:/example.com/>"<script>alert(2121)</script>, popups the javascript anyways thanks for the help :)

Comment: can you explain this with a example of a link?

Comment: for this code use CGI qw( escapeHTML );

my $link_url_html  = escapeHTML($link_url);
my $link_text_html = escapeHTML($link_text);

print(qq{<a href="$link_url_html">$link_text_html</a>\n});